# UrlRequest not working inside a SimpleButton

Tags: php, actionscript-3, flash, cakephp

I have a UrlRequest in my Main Class, that does a request to a server in cakePHP, and its working fine, but when I do the exact same request in a click of a button its not working.

Can someone help me?

This is my code to do the request:

```
var token:String = LoaderInfo(root.loaderInfo).parameters.requestToken;
var myData:URLRequest = new URLRequest("users/personalInfo/"+token);
myData.method = URLRequestMethod.GET;

loader = new URLLoader(myData);
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoaded);
loader.dataFormat=URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT;
loader.load(myData);

function onLoaded(e:Event):void {
    MovieClip(this.root).gotoAndStop("main");
}
```

Click Handler

```
public function SaveProfileButton() {
        addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, mouseClick);
}

private function mouseClick(e:MouseEvent):void{
    MovieClip(this.root).output.text = "loading...";
    send();
}
```

send() is the code to do the request.

Thanks

Comment: Your button click function is getting executed ....right?

Comment: Yes, I already tried to trace.

Comment: Give your click handler code, please

Comment: If you are calling the url from an action you may have forgot to set the webroot in actionscript. `users/personalInfo/"+token` should be something like `/users/personalInfo/"+token` or else you will end up with something like `/controller/action/users/personalInfo/329u0g`

Comment: @SergeHim just added the click handler code.

Comment: @LetterSticker i did not understand what you meant, the same code is working when the app initiate, just before the button appear, but when I click the button to do the request again, doesnt work. The Main Class and the Button Class are in the same folder, so if one works with `users/personalInfo/"+token` why doesn't work in my button?

Comment: Just saying, are you sure the url is correct because you don't have the preceeding `/` before the url

Comment: @LetterSticker I don't have the preceding `/` because its relative path, the swf is in the same location as the folder. And its working in main. Do it in a button does any difference? Or if is not on the Main Class but instead on a SimpleButton Class?

Comment: I already discovered the problem, it was really a minor code mistake, i had `MovieClip(this.root).gotoAndStop("main");` and it cannot be `this.root`, just `root`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may need a cross domain policy xml on your server where the php is. 99% sure. http://www.adobe.com/devnet/articles/crossdomain_policy_file_spec.html